# Desktop Icons Extension not working in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons

Recently upgraded from 18.04 to 19.04 and apparently it was someone's grand idea to remove the ability to add icons to the desktop, for what purpose? who knows.

I've installed nemo, that didn't work

I've installed desktop-icons-extension, that didn't work

I've tried updating the permissions on the desktop folder, that didn't work.

I've run out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of icons are you trying to add? I was able to create symlinks on the desktop, but I had to do it from the terminal.

Comment: Any type of file; jpg, png, .desktop, .txt, I'd like to put any file i want on the desktop

Comment: Try copy-paste to the Desktop folder, not dragging to the actual desktop. I've tested this with folders/files and seems to work OK. Symlinks, however, seem to be a manual (terminal) process.

Comment: In 19.04... specifically the GNOME shell... has changed the way the desktop works. For the most part, only folders (and Home and Trash) can exist there now. So... create a new folder called, say, "Work in Progress". Then use `Files` to move all of your existing (non-folder) items into this new folder, and use it as your "new/current" Desktop.

Comment: I can copy files to the desktop via nautilus/nemo, but i can't launch any .desktop files.

Comment: Creating the extra folder on the desktop is what I'm doing now. There has to be a way to properly restore this feature. I'm genuinely curious as to the thought process behind removing this. It just makes zero sense.

Comment: I just found the way to add .desktop files and make them launchers: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/04/pin-application-shortcuts-desktop-ubuntu-19-04/

Comment: I don't  have the ability to paste anything to the desktop. The Paste option is grayed out for me.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, to answer the rhetorical question you raised in the beginning, [here's the detailed rationale](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/158) provided by GNOME developers. It seems it was *not* done at whim.

Comment: Thanks, I did genuinely want to know what was behind the decision, so i appreciate you sharing the link

Comment: I've switched to Unity for the time being as it still retained the desktop icons capability through the upgrade. I even have compiz back again. Sorry gnome, i gave you a serious try.